# Expected end of Statement Error on Simple Formula Insert

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

`###.value = "=LOOKUP(LEFT(W2),{"C","A","B"},{"Pick Up","Collect","Prepaid"})"`

I want VBA to do this simple formula but getting "Expected: end of Statement" error.
It seems that I need to define something as VBA doesn't recognize character `"{}"` the brackets.

Comment: Use double quotes if you want quotes within VBA strings

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It might be requiring you to end the script like this

```
###.value = "=LOOKUP(LEFT(W2),{"C","A","B"},{"Pick Up","Collect","Prepaid"});"
```

**OR**

```
###.value = "=LOOKUP(LEFT(W2),{"C","A","B"},{"Pick Up","Collect","Prepaid"})";
```

**NOTICE:** the **Semi-colon at the end *';'***.

I'm not a VBA user for a long time. but just try. Delete this answer if its not good enough.

Comment: No vba does not use semi colons at the end of a statement.  And you need double quotes

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that `###` actually symbolizes a cell object (otherwise you would get a compile error):

`###.Value = "=LOOKUP(LEFT(W2),{""C"",""A"",""B""},{""Pick Up"",""Collect"",""Prepaid""})"`

Also, I thought that you would have to change `.Value` to `.Formula`, but I tested and both ways work.